# If C is a chain of set S, $C \subseteq S$ or $C \subseteq S \times S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

I'm doing an exercise, which asks us to prove that "every infinite set $S \subseteq \mathbb N^n_0$ contains an infinite chain $C\subseteq S$." But since C is a chain of set S, C is supposed to be a relation on S, which means, suppose P is a poset of S, $P=(S,\preceq)$, $P \subseteq S \times S$, and $C \subseteq P$, so actually $C \subseteq S \times S$. Or maybe in this context it's also understandable to write $C \subseteq S$?
Could anyone please tell me what's wrong here? I think I've misunderstood some concepts. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $C$ is not supposed to be a relation on $S$. I guess that the relation $\le$ on $S$ is induced from $\Bbb N_0$ and $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\le (y_1,\dots,y_n)=y$ iff $x_i\le y_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: So C is a set of elements which belong to S, instead of being a set of pairs of elements in S? Or maybe it can be said in other way, that C is a totally ordered set instead of a total order?

Comment: @Xichu Yes, [chain $C$ is a totally ordered subset of $S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains).